# Is Provisioning Profile required to Launch App?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am facing a problem with launching my app and discovered it requires me to connect an iOS device and create the provisioning profile - in order to Archive the Xcode project just to launch it.

So am I correct in saying "An iOS device needs to be connected to successfully archive and submit the app project?"

Answer (score 0):

Yep, To launch application on AppStore its required. 
When you would like to install on device then also its required.